# How to migrate SVN to git

Tags: git, subversion

Can someone tell me the steps on how to migrate `svn` to `git`?
I have repositories in `svn` and I want to move all them  to `git` without the loss of data.

Comment: This would be much more appropriate for [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Stackoverflow is for [things related to development](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), including the tools used (there are a lot of VCS questions there). SVN & GIT are not specific to unix or linux.

Comment: SO has this covered in several questions, including some of the pitfalls to beware of. Instead of linking to individual questions (there are a bunch), here is a search result page: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=svn+git+migrate

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Consult [svn2git](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion) that provides you with all the steps. necessary:

- `svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo --metadata`

this is assuming you don't want to update any more changes made later to `svn`.

Answer (score 2):

The git book has two chapter devoted to this question:

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion